# "Con mi esposa fuimos a comer" ¿Error de concordancia?

Tags: concordancia-verbal

He escuchado mucho una construcción en ciertas frases que me suena un poco raro, pero no sé si está correcta o no. Explicaré con un ejemplo.

> "Ayer con mi esposa fuimos a comer"

¿Es correcto decir "fuimos"? ¿O debería ser fui?. Mi duda es porque reacomodando la oración, esta quedaría:
"Ayer fui a comer con mi esposa"
Entonces no sé si una simple reacomodación de la oración hace que lo correcto sea cambiar el número en el verbo. ¿Quizá debería decirse mejor "Ayer mi esposa y yo fuimos a comer"?

Recordé esta pregunta porque esta semana leí en un [periódico](http://www.semana.com/nacion/articulo/gobierno-de-cuba-retiene-y-deporta-a-andres-pastrana/559339) en línea :

> “Con el expresidente Quiroga estamos detenidos por el gobierno cubano en el aeropuerto de La Habana”, contó Pastrana en su cuenta oficial de Twitter.

Comment: Sé que los comentarios no están para poner (posibles) respuestas, y si puedo luego amplío, pero supongo que el contexto puede tener algo que ver? "Ayer con mi esposa fuimos a comer [mis hijos y yo]". Si fuésemos solo mi esposa y yo, coincido en que debería ser "fui". En cualquier caso es cierto que esa sintaxis casi parece propia del maestro Yoda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pues aunque no lo parezca es correcto, en la entrada sobre la [concordancia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5) de DPD en el punto 4.3 podemos leer lo siguiente:

> (...) La posibilidad de poner el verbo en plural
>   en estos casos ha dado lugar a una construcción especial, extendida en
>   varios países de América y, en España, en zonas de influencia del
>   catalán, que consiste en poner el verbo en primera persona del plural
>   cuando el sujeto es un «yo» elidido que lleva asociado un complemento
>   precedido de *con*, presente en la oración: *«Dile a la Rubia que con
>   Pablo estuvimos haciendo el elogio más subido que puede hacerse por
>   dos poetas de una dama ausente»* (Asturias *Carta* [Guat. 1950]); *«Vos
>   sabés, Tita, que con Ana María fuimos una pareja que nos quisimos
>   mucho»* (Pavlovsky *Potestad* [Arg. 1985]).  En ambos ejemplos el contexto
>   permite determinar con claridad que en la acción están implicados solo
>   dos individuos, el yo que habla y la persona que se menciona en el
>   complemento preposicional; así, las construcciones resaltadas en los
>   ejemplos equivalen, respectivamente, a *yo y Pablo estuvimos*, *yo y Ana
>   María fuimos* (...)

Aunque también advierte:

> (...) se recomienda evitar esta
>   construcción en aquellos casos en que el hablante perciba el riesgo de
>   no ser correctamente interpretado.

Comment: Al menos para mí (en Argentina) casi no hay alternativa al uso de esta construcción; decir "Fulano y yo estuvimos haciendo tal o cual cosa" suena raro, quizá "demasiado correcto".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que siempre y cuando puedas identificar el sujeto en la oración puedes utilizar el verbo adecuado

Si bien el sujeto en :

> yo con mi esposa fuimos a comer

Se puede entender que el sujeto del que se esta hablando pueden ser tanto "Yo" como "yo con mi esposa".

Sin embargo podemos encontrar diferencias de significado

> yo con mi esposa fui a comer puede significar que solo yo comi

Mientras que

> yo con mi esposa fuimos a comer significa que ambos comieron

Tal vez un ejemplo mas diferenciable sea mejor :

> yo con mi esposa compre una bufanda

Creo que aqui esta claro que fui YO quien compro la bufanda

> yo con mi esposa compramos una bufanda

Tambien queda claro que ambos compramos una bufanda.

Resumen TLDR;

Yo con mi esposa Fuimos = Yo y mi esposa fuimos

Yo con mi esposa fui = Yo fui con mi esposa